# How to have an Apache-served Flask website with a WordPress blog at /blog?

Tags: php, python, wordpress, flask

I realize there are multiple similar questions already but I could not seem to find an answer that made it clear to me what I needed to do:

I have a DigitalOcean droplet which is serving a Flask application.  I would now like to have a WordPress blog at /blog.  I went through [DigitalOcean's WordPress setup instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-lamp-on-ubuntu-16-04) but I they did not include a description of how to modify the Apache `.conf` file to point to the WordPress `index.php` file.

I tried adding an `Alias` to my `.conf` file but it does not work.  When I go to `/blog` right now I see the default Apache "It works!" page.  However, if I go to `www.rhymecraft.guru/blog/wp-admin` it does load the admin panel.

#### Apache .conf file

(Note that I installed WordPress into `/var/www/html`.)

```
WSGIDaemonProcess rhymecraft.guru processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
WSGIProcessGroup rhymecraft.guru

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.rhymecraft.guru
        ServerAlias rhymecraft.guru
        ServerAdmin xxxx@gmail.com

        Alias /blog /var/www/html
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/rhymecraft/server/rhymecraft.wsgi

        DocumentRoot /var/www/rhymecraft/server

        Alias /robots.txt /var/www/rhymecraft/server/robots.txt
        Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/rhymecraft/server/robots.txt

        <Directory /var/www/rhymecraft/server>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>

        Alias /static /var/www/rhymecraft/server/static     

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.rhymecraft.guru [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =rhymecraft.guru
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerName www.rhymecraft.guru
                ServerAlias rhymecraft.guru
                ServerAdmin xxxx@gmail.com

                Alias /blog /var/www/html
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/rhymecraft/server/rhymecraft.wsgi

                DocumentRoot /var/www/rhymecraft/server

                Alias /robots.txt /var/www/rhymecraft/server/robots.txt
                Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/rhymecraft/server/robots.txt

                <Directory /var/www/rhymecraft/server>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>

                Alias /static /var/www/rhymecraft/server/static

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/rhymecraft.guru/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/rhymecraft.guru/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

#### Related questions and why they didn't answer my question

- [How to serve Wordpress blog at /blog/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39506609/how-to-serve-wordpress-blog-at-blog)

  - The person asking this question is using Nginx, not Apache.
- [Adding Wordpress blog to an existing website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522898/adding-wordpress-blog-to-an-existing-website)

  - This person wants to host his blog on an entirely different machine.
- [Setting up Wordpress and Flask on Apache2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27260284/setting-up-wordpress-and-flask-on-apache2)

  - The person asking this question says (in his answer to his question) that he was able to get both Flask and WordPress working together, but I don't see what in his `.conf` file is enabling WordPress.  The only person other than the OP to post an answer was suggesting a method that used a subdomain to host the blog rather than a subdirectory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working.

Two things I needed to do:

1. I needed to have the line `Alias /blog /var/www/html` in *both* VirtualHost entries.  At first I had only put it in the port 80 (normal-HTTP-traffic) entry, but forgot to put it in the port 443 (HTTPS traffic) entry.

   - Note that you'll only have these two VirtualHost records if you're using HTTPS.  I'm using Cloudflare and forcing all requests to the website to use HTTPS, so the fact that I forgot to add the Alias record to the port 443 VirtualHost record was enough to make it appear to not be working.
2. I needed to delete the default Apache `index.html` file that was in the `/var/www/html` directory.

   - Apache was preferring to use that over the `index.php` file that WordPress had added to the directory.